# React native state declaration difference

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What's the difference between declaring state as given below:

```
export default class BlackFade extends React.Component {
 state = { fListData : [] }
}

export default class BlackFade extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { fListData : [] }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are doing the same job

First one `state = { fListData : [] }` is making use of 
[class property proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) which is stage 3 proposal under the hood which is doing the same job as :

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { fListData : [] }
 }
```

**NOTE:** There are total 4 stages of a proposal after that , proposal will be a part of a Language

You can compare and check both of them on [Babel Transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/)

Comment: which one is the best practice to use?

Comment: At this point of time (first one is staged 3 proposal) It’s all about personal preference , first one you have to write less lines of code and second one more